# Unix script for list the running application/cron jobs with port number and general information on host

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix

Unix script (combination of ps cron and docker ps ) for list the running application/cron jobs with port number and general information(cpu usage) on host

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN > Its shows me the IP and port but not the application name 

ps -aux > Its shows the application but not port info.

top > Its shows the application with all usage but not port info. 

I want the script to list the application with network port with other info like cpu usage for that application on the server. Thanks
```

Comment: Thanks, @kaylum, Updated the question with more details. General info means CPU usage for that application.

Comment: would appreciate for help here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you run netstat with `sudo`, you have app info:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0 0 127.0.0.53:53   0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      570/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0 0 0.0.0.0:22      0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      762/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0 0 127.0.0.1:631   0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      5893/cupsd          
tcp6       0 0 :::22           :::*          LISTEN      762/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0 0 ::1:631         :::*          LISTEN      5893/cupsd
```